# Why CM13 of Oneplus 2 resets itself Setting Show pattern dots?

Tags: cyanogenmod, security, oneplus-two

I found out that CM loses often its setting about the visibility of security dots in the lock screen. 
This is frustrating because I am using 6x6 net with a difficult pattern. It is challenging to pass the login. 
Cases where I have seen that CM forgets the setting

1. Install any app of unknown sources etc Amazon underground
2. Leave the setting of unknown sources open

I managed to pass the code without the dots after 20 attempts. The phone had reseted the setting *Show pattern dots*. 
Other changes in the phone

- I see only the dot pattern in the lock screen, nothing else; before, I saw Camera and Phone at the bottom bar in Fig. 1

Fig. 1 Lock Screen now, Fig. 2 Settings in Lock Screen View 1, Fig. 3 Settings in Lock Screen View 2

[image]
   [image]
   [image]

Phone: Oneplus 2
OS: Cyanogenmod 13

Comment: I am just curious why not use FP instead of pattern?

Comment: FP is fingerprint. I do not want to use it. It is less secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issues was an internal issue in OnePlus with Android 6.